# Send multiple chunks in the same HTTP request

Tags: javascript

In browser JavaScript, is there a way to "open a HTTP request" and write/send data to it like a file handle and have the API read this as one HTTP request? Or is chunking over multiple HTTP requests the only way? (I assume so since chunking is a popular method)

e.g.

```js
const req = new HTTPConnection("PUT", url);
async for (const chunk of asyncDataSource) {
    req.write(chunk);
}
req.close();
```

Comment: I recommend you do some research on [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). If your looking for a particular framework [socket.IO](https://socket.io/) may be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or the good old [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

I assume you want to upload some files or image/video?

So you can do it like this with XmlHttpRequest:

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
const file = fileInput.files[0];

const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PUT", url);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
    console.log(req.responseText);
  }
};
req.send(file);
```

Or slighly more modern approach with the Fetch API:

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
const file = fileInput.files[0];

const body = new FormData();
body.append("file", file);

fetch(url, {
  method: "PUT",
  body: body,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": file.type,
  },
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Comment: I want to process the file data in browser before uploading. Large files can't be held in memory and I don't know how to put chunks of processed bytes back into one "blob" or send whole thing to server in one HTTP request. I've already decided to go with chunking, so thanks for your help anyway.